# Push data inside an array index. React Native JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am trying to compare, find and push data inside an array. But getting following error

> Error => TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[index].push')

I have following JSON/Array

```
[
  {
     "category":"Super",
     "id":"1",
     "images":[],
     "status":"open",
     "url":"some url here"
  },
  {
     "category":"Pizza",
     "entitlement_id":"pizza_pack_ent",
     "id":"2",
     "images":[],
     "package_id":"pizza_pack_single",
     "status":"locked",
     "url":"some url here"
  }
]
```

I want to push `packages` object inside matching category so json/array will be as follows

```
[
  {
     "category":"Super",
     "id":"1",
     "images":[],
     "status":"open",
     "url":"some url here"
  },
  {
     "category":"Pizza",
     "entitlement_id":"pizza_pack_ent",
     "id":"2",
     "images":[],
     "package_id":"pizza_pack_single",
     "status":"locked",
     "url":"some url here",
     "packages": [
         {
           "id":"abcds"
         },
         {
            "id": "xyz"
         }
      ]
  }
]
```

Following is the code what I was trying to do:

```
data.forEach((category, index) => { //data is main json/array in which I want to push packages
       packages.forEach((pckg, idx) => {
            if(pckg.identifier === category.package_id){
              // data[category].push(pckg); //not worked
              data[index].push(pckg); //not worked either
            }
                
        })
 })
 console.log(data);
```

Comment: `data` is an array of objects, so `data[index]` will be an object. You can't push to an object.

Comment: How to convert that object into an array then?

Comment: or what is the workaround for this?

Comment: Based on your required result you don't want to "convert" an object to array. You want to create a `package` property on  that object with an empty array (if not existing) and push to that

Comment: As a side note, also note that evaluating `if(pckg.identifier === category.package_id)` might unexpectedly return `true` if both the `pckg.identifier` and `category.package_id` are undefined. So if you have categories where the `package_id` is missing (such as the first element in your example array), you may want to address that as well.

Comment: @pkorhone your're right, edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your `packages` array look like, but this should give you the expected result:

```
data.forEach((category, index) => { //data is main json/array in which I want to push packages
       packages.forEach((pckg, idx) => {
            if(category.package_id  && pckg.identifier === category.package_id){
              if (!category.packages) {
                  category.packages = [];
              }
                category.packages.push(pckg)
            }
                
        })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var packages = [
         {
           "id":"abcds"
         },
         {
            "id": "xyz"
         }
      ]
var categoryList = [
  {
     "category":"Super",
     "id":"1",
     "images":[],
     "status":"open",
     "url":"some url here"
  },
  {
     "category":"Pizza",
     "entitlement_id":"pizza_pack_ent",
     "id":"2",
     "images":[],
     "package_id":"pizza_pack_single",
     "status":"locked",
     "url":"some url here"
  }
]
categoryList.forEach(x=>x.packages=[...packages]);
```